# jquery - sliding between pages

Tags: jquery, slide

I want to develop my new website with a smooth moves between pages. Each page will be 100% width and height. is there any script in jquery which helps to achieve that? below i am presenting flow of the website one by one.[image]

I know there are many different sliders but usually they are overloaded with other functionalities..

thanks!

Comment: If your website is just one big slider/carousel I can't imagine that would be very good for SEO. Or is that not a consideration you have to worry about for your project?

Comment: This kind of thing i would build bespoke, so many things you need to think about to keep your site fast and SEO friendly. I don't think a jQuery plugin will cut it. Could be wrong.

Comment: this will be an internal site so i don't bother with SEO ;)